# Mnemonics of my WiX Burn custom bootstrapper UI not working

Tags: c#, winforms, wix, burn

I made a WiX Burn custom bootstrapper UI using WinForms and put some mnemonics for buttons in my UI using the ampersand(&) notation, like `&Next`. But it does not work ignoring my key input. How can I fix this? Following code is part of my bootstrapper application.

```
namespace MyBA_UI
{
    public class MyBA : BootstrapperApplication
    {
        public static Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

            var form = new Mainform(this);

            form.Show();

            Dispatcher.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096356/678558), this problem might be related to mixed use of WinForms and WPF(I firstly wrote my BA using WPF but, changed it to WinForms). So, I edited my code to the following:

```
namespace MyBA_UI
{
    public class MyBA : BootstrapperApplication
    {
        protected override void Run()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Mainform(this));
        }
    }
}
```

and it works very well.